# How can I apply a threshold for a bar graph in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

I've gone through this particular [ticket](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/5037), which pretty much talks about adding a threshold line, to a `line graph`.

In my case, I'm having a `bar graph` like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9PaR.jpg) where I need to have a threshold, lets say for example in the above graph itself I should be able to show the difference in each and every bar.

In other words as per the above graph, it's displaying the `sum` of `chargeamount` according to the `filter` I've given. What I need to do is, to show the difference using a color in the same bar itself if the `sum` of `chargeamount` is greater than 50,000.

So is there a way that I can show the bar with the default color for the filter (ie: the ones which are less than 50,000) and the rest should be shown in a different color conveying the threshold. So that the user can see the difference in the bar itself,  whether they've achieved more than 50k.

Is this possible using a `bar graph` or should I be get going with some other graph?

**EDIT**:

Just noticed that this [issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4482) is still open. Any enhancement over that, or any work around available atm?

Any help could be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Timelion to the rescue! Altough haven't figured out stacking something like this could work for now:

```
.es(*).if(gt,100,.es(*),null).bars().color(red) .es(*).if(lte,100,.es(*),null).bars().color(blue) .static(100)
```

Here is what it does:

1.Get every datapoint with a value greater than 100 and null everything else. Make a bar graph with color red.

2.Get every datapoint with a value less than equal 100 and null everything else. Make a bar graph and color it red.

3.Finally draw a line at value 100.

What you need to do is replace the `*` with a valid expression and you should be good to go!

There might be a way to subtract the value and add it on another graph but I haven't figured out how to do that. If I find a solution I will update this answer.