# Kibana graph for anomaly detection

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

With some data loaded into ES using LS, is there a way to mention in Kibana a threshold and display an indicator it breaches the threshold. For example number of transaction in an hour across the system lets set to 200. When gets refreshed the dashboard, it should indicate in red or something when it goes beyond 200 in a time line graph or some visualization. 
So If we see for whole day some hours will be red or spikes and most will be green or lower lines. This will be useful for us to display capability of anamoly detection. We are still working to understand Prelert but this kind of detection in Kibana will help us to see in graphs.

Regards,
Raj

Answer (score 1):

There's no such direct **threshold** mechanism which you could apply on the Kibana Visualizations as the issue's still [open](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4482).

But then a workaround for this could be to go with a *scripted field* in Kibana so that you could add up a constant value and use it as a margin in your visualization. Note that The scripted field may work for line visualizations, but it isn't compatible with an area visualization using sub-aggregations.

**OR**  you could use a *filter* and *stacked lines* with having one color for above threshold and another color for the ones which under the threshold.

You could still follow up on [this](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/5037) ticket and this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478503/how-can-i-apply-a-threshold-for-a-bar-graph-in-kibana) could be handy. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.